Playwright Scrapy Scraper only Running once or twice, then hangs
In my application I am using a simplified Scrapy Playwright scraper to crawl domains by first received URL. The logic works well on the first URL received and if I send another URL quickly it will process that too.
Sometimes if I send 3 URL's fast enough it will process all and start crawling, but usually the 2nd or 3rd URL passed to the gRPC server it goes through everything in the MySpider class logic and it never reaches the "parse" method. It just hangs indefinitely at 2024-04-09 17:09:55 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
I have tried both on my Windows 10 machine or Macbook M2. Both produce same results. The try catch on process.start doesnt help because while it does throw a generic error 2nd time I dont see an error message every time and it throws error on second ingested URL but still runs without issue sometimes.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting Server")
    instantiate_grpc_server()

def instantiate_grpc_server():
    # Create a gRPC server
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))

    # Add the service to the server
    scraper_pb2_grpc.add_MessageServicer_to_server(MessageServicer(), server)

    # Start the server on the specified port
    server.add_insecure_port(loopback + ':' + grpc_scraper_server)
    server.start()
    print("gRPC server started. Listening on " + grpc_scraper_server + '...')

    # Keep the server running indefinitely
    server.wait_for_termination()

# Define the service by subclassing the generated service class
class MessageServicer(scraper_pb2_grpc.MessageServicer):
def Send(self, request, context):
    # Handle incoming message request
    ...
                    pool = ThreadPool(processes=5)
                    task = pool.apply_async(run_crawl, args=(url_to_scrape, request.sender, dborigin))
                    active_tasks[url_to_scrape] = task

                    print('Send response back') 
                    ...
   
def run_crawl(url_to_scrape, user, dborigin, wait=5, iter=1):
    process = CrawlerProcess(
        settings={
            "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36",
        }
    )
    print("Initiate Crawl")
    process.crawl(MySpider, url=url_to_scrape, user=user, dborigin=dborigin)
    print("Attempt Process Start", iter)
    try:
        process.start()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to Start Crawl Process", str(e))
        # Send local event to retry crawl later
    print("Crawl Done", url_to_scrape)


def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
    self.start_urls = [url]
    # Initialize database connection
    print("Instantiate Db Connection")
    DATABASE_URL = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
    self.engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)

    print("Build Session")
    Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
    self.session = Session()
    print("Spider Created, running!", self.url, self.session) # Reaches here every time

 async def parse(self, response):
    print('url:', response.url) # On 2nd or 3rd URL ingested via gRPC this never prints
    ...

See final log info:
Spider Created, running! https://losangelesapparel.net/products/thighhi-lw-thigh-high-leg-warmers?variant=43126180610227 <sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x000001E5879789D0>
Url Exists <__main__.Url object at 0x000001E58990FAF0>
2024-04-09 17:09:55 [scrapy.addons] INFO: Enabled addons:
[]
2024-04-09 17:09:55 [py.warnings] WARNING: G:\Development\Scraper\web-crawler-python-base\scraper\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\request.py:254: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: '2.6' is a deprecated value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting.

It is also the default value. In other words, it is normal to get this warning if you have not defined a value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting. This is so for backward compatibility reasons, but it will change in a future version of Scrapy.

See the documentation of the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting for information on how to handle this deprecation.
  return cls(crawler)

2024-04-09 17:09:55 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2024-04-09 17:09:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.memdebug.MemoryDebugger',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2024-04-09 17:09:55 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 32,
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP': 32,
 'MEMDEBUG_ENABLED': True,
 'MEMDEBUG_NOTIFY': ['admin@domain.tld'],
 'MEMUSAGE_NOTIFY_MAIL': ['admin@domain.tld'],
 'REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE': 32,
 'TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED': False,
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
               '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36'}
2024-04-09 17:09:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['__main__.ProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2024-04-09 17:09:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2024-04-09 17:09:55 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2024-04-09 17:09:55 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2024-04-09 17:09:55 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

There is also this unhandled error on first crawl. Unsure if it is related. It is not my most pressing issue so Ive ignored it for now:
2024-04-09 17:13:00 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Development\Scraper\web-crawler-python-base\scraper\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 504, in fireEvent
    DeferredList(beforeResults).addCallback(self._continueFiring)
  File "G:\Development\Scraper\web-crawler-python-base\scraper\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 620, in addCallback
    return self.addCallbacks(callback, callbackArgs=args, callbackKeywords=kwargs)
  File "G:\Development\Scraper\web-crawler-python-base\scraper\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 533, in addCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
  File "G:\Development\Scraper\web-crawler-python-base\scraper\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1075, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "G:\Development\Scraper\web-crawler-python-base\scraper\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 516, in _continueFiring
    callable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Development\Scraper\web-crawler-python-base\scraper\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\ossignal.py", line 26, in install_shutdown_handlers
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, function)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\signal.py", line 47, in signal
    handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
builtins.ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter

